# How to use pointclouds from Kinect?

Tags: ros, navigation, hector, robot-pose-ekf, pointclouds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to use the pointclouds from the Kinect to do ICP and do lokalization with Hector Mapping or robot_pose_ekf. Is there any help how to use Kinect with pointclouds for that purpose?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63891/how-to-use-pointclouds-from-kinect?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that your best start would be to look into the [openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) package this will help you to get the raw data from the kinect. The next thing I would recommend is to look into the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/). They are very heavily tied to ROS and provide a very robust library for handling RGB-D data.

Finally PCL offers many tutorials that discuss the topics you want to look into check out the following:

- [ICP](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php#iterative-closest-point)
- [Localization](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__registration.html) (map building)
- As for robot_pose_ekf I do not know what this is but there is a ROS page [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) that seems to cover the concept and the use of the ROS node pretty well so please check that out.

Hope this helps.
BadRobot

---

Originally posted by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) with karma: 91 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1